# Sophistication of Series[...]

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion

I'll give a concrete example and I hope that my general question will be clear.

Say I have three variables, $f$, $g$, $h$, and I know that $f=\mathcal O(x)$, $g=\mathcal O(x^2)$, $h=\mathcal O(x^3)$ ([$\mathcal O$-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) or something of that sort. Now, I want to do a series expansion of expressions involving $f$, $g$, $h$ to a consistent order in $x$. For example, if I write `Series[..., {x,0,4}]` I want to keep terms like `f^3` and `f g` but to throw away terms like`f g^2` and `g h`.

Is there a simple way to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

`Normal@Series[expr/.{f->x f, g->x^2 g, h->x^3 h},{x,0,4}] /.x->1`